# How to count punctuation marks in a String in java?

Tags: java, methods, count, punctuation

I need to write a program to count certain punctuation marks in a string. I have this code I thought would work, but at every charAt, i have an error that says the left hand of the assignment must be a variable. Need help fixing this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    String s = kbd.next();

    countPunctuation(s);
}
public static int countPunctuation(String s)
{
    int periodCount = 0;
    int commaCount = 0;
    int semicolonCount = 0;
    int colonCount = 0;
    int exclamationCount = 0;
    int questionCount = 0;
    int total = 0;


    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) = ".")
        {
            periodCount++;
            total++;
        }
        if(s.charAt(i) = ",")
        {
            commaCount++;
            total++;
        }
        if(s.charAt(i) = ";")
        {
            semicolonCount++;
            total++;
        }
        if(s.charAt(i) = ":")
        {
            colonCount++;
            total++;
        }
        if(s.charAt(i) = "!")
        {
            exclamationCount++;
            total++;
        }
        if(s.charAt(i) = "?")
        {
            questionCount++;
            total++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("There are " + periodCount + " periods in this String.");
    System.out.println("There are " + commaCount + " commas in this String.");
    System.out.println("There are " + semicolonCount + " semicolons in this String.");
    System.out.println("There are " + colonCount + " colons in this String.");
    System.out.println("There are " + exclamationCount + " exclamation marks in this String.");
    System.out.println("There are " + questionCount + " quesiton marks in this String.");


    return total;
}
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator in Java, `==` checks for equality.  Also, `"."` is a `String`, and you want to compare characters, so you need to use `'.'` instead (and likewise for the other characters).

Comment: Instead of `for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)` you can use `for(char ch : s.toCharArray())`. This way `ch` will contain value normally stored in `s.charAt(i)` so your code would be little cleaner (also characters are surrounded with `'`, not `"`) `if (ch == '.'){...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality check is with `==` not with `=`. You need to have something like `if(s.charAt(i) == '.')` or you can use switch for this case:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    switch(s.charAt(i)) { 
     case '.':
        periodCount++;
        break;
     case ',':
        commaCount++;
        break;
     ... // similar conditions for others
    }
    total += 1;
}
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly there is no need for `total` since we already have `s.length()`.

Answer (score 1):

Idk if this will help, but I found a small Error

Change:

```
String s = kbd.next();
```

To:

```
String s = kbd.nextLine();
```

I think that should definitely fix it.

Why?:

```
next();        -is mostly used for characters, as it doesn't get the whole line.
nextLine();    -gets the entire line, which for your code, you'd want.
```

And like that guy said, your using

```
=   -instead of-   ==
```

"=" is used for assigned vars and stuff
"==" is to check, like if (String s == ";")